# Stack guard might have disabled?

Tags: java, ubuntu, nullpointerexception, gpu, rootbeer

I am trying to run the first example in `rootbeer` library, which you can find from [here](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1).

The issue is, even though I followed all of their instructions, I am getting the following message when I am trying to run the Jar

```
root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin/JavaJars/HelloWordGPU# java -jar HelloWorldGPU.jar
OpenJDK Client VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/libcuda.so.319.37 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.trifort.rootbeer.runtime.Rootbeer.run(Rootbeer.java:104)
        at ScalarMult.test(ScalarMult.java:13)
        at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

I am not a Linux person, so I do not understand how to execute this command properly. I also don't understand what they mean by that message, because this is the first time I am on GPU programming. But I know messing with GPU with wrong commands would be a problem.

Comment: try: sudo execstack -c /usr/lib/libcuda.so

Comment: @Salil What if we don't have `execstack`?

Comment: Before trying to run `execstack` or anything similar, double check that you have `rootbeer` for the correct architecture. At least that was the problem for me when running eclipse MAT.

Answer (score 11):

Type: `execstack --version` to check if you already have execstack installed.

If you get command not found type: `sudo apt-get install execstack -y --force-yes`

Type `sudo execstack -c <file>` 
e.g `sudo execstack -c /usr/lib/libcuda.so`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, This was my first answer so sorry for the malformation.

Comment: I did this multiple times and it still gives me same error

Answer (score 4):

1: Check execstack version using following command to find execstack installed or not

```
execstack --version
```

2: If execstack not installed then install using following command

```
sudo apt-get install execstack -y --force-yes
```

3: After successful installation execute following command

```
sudo execstack -c <filepath>
```

**eg:** *sudo execstack -c /usr/lib/libjpcap.so*

Comment: it is giving the following error
**execstack: cannot get the ELF header: Format error: reference outside file**

Comment: This had no effect in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not running 32-bit Java. If you run java -d64, the 32-bit version will print an error.

Comment: Thanks @dhule (also @andrej). I could have searched for hours (or maybe days).

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not running 32-bit jar on 64-bit jvm first

Comment: are you sure that jar files are platform-dependent?

Answer (score 0):

What does the file `/usr/lib/libcuda.so.319.37` contain?

If the file is a **0-byte-file**, there is something really wrong, so try to repair your system by reinstalling that library.

I had the same problem in smartgit, where a library in the local config folder was used, which was somehow corrupted and was a 0 byte file. So deleting the config folder and restarting the app worked for me. This could be a solution here too.