# Warning when using 32-bit library to build on 64 bit VM

Tags: c

I am trying to build a file using an application which uses this C library "libhadoop.so". When doing so, the following warning message appears:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/user/hadoop-
2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will
 try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', 
or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

Is there any way I can prevent the warning from appearing?

Comment: Did you try the recommendations it gave you?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but than also same problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution given at [Stack guard might have disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345891/stack-guard-might-have-disabled) will help you, too.

Check for package "`execstack`" with: `execstack --version`
 If not found, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install execstack
```

Execute the command recommended inside of the message:

```
sudo execstack -c /home/user/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so
```