# You have loaded library /tmp/... which might have disabled stack guard

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal, comsol

During the installation from an .iso I have this error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/setup.4871/lib/glnxa64/gcc/libgcc_s.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack
```

after this command:

```
./setup
```

I followed this link : [Stack guard might have disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345891/stack-guard-might-have-disabled) but it doesn't work.

```
> sudo execstack -c /tmp/setup.4871/lib/glnxa64/gcc/libgcc_s.so
> execstack: "/tmp/setup.4871/lib/glnxa64/gcc/libgcc_s.so" is not an ELF
> file
```

I'm using the last version of Ubuntu, it is strange because on Kali Linux it worked without any problems. Any suggestion? Thanks