# Error : Java ME SDK not launching application, Why?

Tags: java, java-me

I'm working on J2ME application. When i try to launch application it gives me error about sublime. so that library is,

```
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library 
> /home/user/Documents/JavaME/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so which might have 
> disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
```

with message :-

> It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c > 
>    ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
>    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
>    /home/cis/Documents/Andreas/J2ME/bin/sublime.so: 
>    /home/cis/Documents/Andreas/J2ME/bin/sublime.so: wrong ELF class: 
>    ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)

I also checked [Stack guard might have disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345891/stack-guard-might-have-disabled)
But nothing seems to work here.
Please help me. Thanks in advance...!

Comment: There isn't actually a question here. Please edit the question to clearly express what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @hardillb :) i'm new to this platform.

Comment: Better, but the message is clearly labelled as a warning, not an error